# Is matter in space, or independent from it, but interracts?

Tags: universe, space, matter

Considering the "hierarchy" of the Universe, or the world in a broad sense, as I understand it consists of matter, matter consists of "substance" (fermions), and fields and so on.

How is space related to such hierarchy? Is it related at all?

Is space (space-time) on the top of hierarchy, and it includes a matter, or matter and space are separate?

[image]

Comment: What experiment would you propose to answer your question? Without an experiment, it is just words, not physics.

Comment: @JohnDoty, can't answer this question currently, so can't argue that this is philosophy, rather than physics

Comment: I can certainly imagine (and define mathematically) an empty world without any "substance" in it (no matter), while space and time are still there (example:  the empty Minkowski spacetime).  But I'm unable to imagine the presence of matter (or "substance") without the spacetime as a container.  So *spacetime* is more "fundamental" than matter fields.

Comment: @Cham Something that exists only in your mind can hardly be called "fundamental" to physics. The foundations of physics are experiments and observations

Comment: @JohnDoty, my comment was to say that we could develop theories of spacetimes without matter, but we can't create theories of matter without spacetime (it wont have any sense!).  So theoretically, spacetime is more fundamental than matter fields.  By "fundamental", I mean *irreducible concepts* that allow us to make sense of things.  So "spacetime" is certainly fundamental!

Comment: @Cham So, the fundamental fact is that matter is observed to exist. That demands other concepts, but those concepts are not fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

According to the general theory of relativity, spacetime is a field $g_{\mu \nu }(x)$ that interacts with the other fields and "substances". Its quanta are expected to be spin-2 bosons. In this framework, "spacetime" is subsumed in the "Fields" child-node of your diagram (B).

According to quantum field theory, your "fermions" or "substances" are also just fields.

So you really just need:

$\text{Fields} \rightarrow \text{Fermions and Bosons}$

But it is probably too early to call the above framework a "theory of everything" as it hasn't incorporated quantum gravity yet. Just take Quantum Field Theory to be a model of the world, instead of the world itself. Gravity is known to be a field at only the classical level. We don't know if Quantum Gravity is a field theory or string theory or whatever.

Comment: If spacetime *is* the field $g$, what is the $x$ in the argument of $g$?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Those are the manifold points. Some people would call that the spacetime itself but it doesn't doesn't make sense, e.g. in a manifold with an Euclidean metric, or in a manifold without a metric, to distinguish a time-direction. So there is no reason to call it "spacetime". The metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ is what corresponds to length and time measurements and the Minkowski signature is what identifies a time direction. The manifold is just a mathematical set on which we define fields.

Comment: Ok, but what are the elements of the manifold? Events?